# Splitting and exporting quadrant of big map

Tags: pyqgis, clip, print-composer

I'm quite new to Python and QGIS (and to PyQGIS).

I have a very big map, made of many layers, and a fishnet overlaying it. I would like to clip and export the map for each quadrant (or maybe just export each quadrant, as in noticed the resulted pdf is clipped automatically). So I guess I should iterate the grid polygons, create a layout for everyone, and export it.

Does someone have advice or examples about it?

As a coder (well... js) I kind of understand the principle but again, very new to this environment.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I finally figured that out:
https://github.com/piLeoni/fishNet2Layouts

Comment: Please add the contents of the link to your answer in case the link breaks etc.